# Ember js how to use the BasicAdapter

Tags: ember.js

I am looking for a guide that will help me understand syncing models in ember. I tried to use the RestAdapter on the latest build and I am getting an error. So I decided to use the BasicAdapter based on [stabilizing ember data on the ember js site](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/03/22/stabilizing-ember-data.html).

Here is my model:

```
App.Accounts = DS.Model.extend({
 name:DS.attr('string')
,date:DS.attr('date')
})
```

Here is where I declare the sync functions for the model.

```
App.Accounts.sync = {
list: function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: contextPath + 'account/list',
        success: function(data) {
            this.load()
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        },
        async: false
    });
}
}
```

I am calling the list function in a setup controller:

```
App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
setupController:function(){
    App.Accounts.list()
}
})
```

The function does not execute. What is the correct way to call sync functions in an ember application? Also, I could use a blog/article on this topic.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: I'm in a similar boat. Definitely curious about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out [Ember Model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model) it gives you a basic adapter without having to use EmberData.

Erik has a tutorial at embercasts.com you may need to signup to be beta user.

```
var attr = Ember.attr;

App.User = Ember.Model.extend({
  id: attr(),
  name: attr()
});

App.User.url = "/users";
App.User.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create();

var newUser = App.User.create({name: "Erik"});
newUser.save(); // POST to /users.json

var existingUser = App.User.find(1); // GET /users/1.json
existingUser.set('name', 'Kris');
existingUser.get('isDirty'); // => true
existingUser.save(); // PUT /users/1.json
```

Cheers